# Interpolating the color points throughout the image

Tags: c++, image-processing

I have been trying to solve this problem for several days now, and I am official stuck; I need to draw the topological plot of an eeg signal on the brain, and I didn't find any cpp libraries that already do so. There is such library in Matlab, but that is considered a last resort, for now it is prefered to do all the processing in c++.

Basically what I need is a way to interpolate the color points in image 1 in order to produce image 2. They belong to different eeg diagrams, which is why they do not match.

My question is: is there any commonly known algorithm that will allow me to interpolate the points in image 1 in order to produce image 2?

[image: Original figure with the color points]
[image: Figure with the colors interpolate]

Comment: pick one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation#Irregular_grid_.28scattered_data.29

Comment: do you have data on the confidence of correctness of each point?

Comment: Thank you @Pavel, I am going to check it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

I like the "[Irregular grid (scattered data)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation#Irregular_grid_.28scattered_data.29)" methods suggested by @Pavel in a comment.

To implement a simple but fast rendering solution where each output color is based on only three source colors, you could do a [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) and then use [Gouraud shading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) to render the triangles using the known vertex colors.

Your sample image 2 is "softer" than that so I suspect it uses a higher-order interpolation scheme.

Since the interpolation method influences interpretation of the data be careful to select one that reduces incorrect interpretations.